# How to merge lines broken by newlines inside a double quoted field?

Tags: csv

Imagine input is:

```
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Z,KYEEI9,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,"1GH8
",KYEEID,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Y,KYEEIJ,1/1/2016 Contract Code
```

I would like to have the 3 lines(with newline as #### for example):

```
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Z,KYEEI9,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,"1GH8####",KYEEID,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Y,KYEEIJ,1/1/2016 Contract Code
```

Thanks,
Emanuel

Comment: Do you want the lines joined with 4 hash-marks, or do those just indicate where the lines were joined (by removing the newline)?

Comment: Yes i need some special sequence so that when storing in database I will then convert back #### into newline, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**`awk`** solution:

```
awk -F',' '{ printf "%s%s", $0, ($NF ~ /^".+[^"]$/? "####" : ORS) }' file
```

The output:

```
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Z,KYEEI9,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,"1GH8####",KYEEID,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Y,KYEEIJ,1/1/2016 Contract Code
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks Roman.. I will test it tuesday when im back in office.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r ':x /$/ { N; s/\r?\n\s*"/####"/; bx}' inputfile
```

`\r?` make it work for both Linux and Windows text files

Answer (score 0):

The data is appropriately quoted and should be readable by any CSV-aware parser.

To remove the newline that may occur in the 5th field of your header-less CSV file, you may use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) like so:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put '$5 = sub($5,"\n","")' file
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Z,KYEEI9,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1GH8,KYEEID,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Y,KYEEIJ,1/1/2016 Contract Code
```

This rewrites the 5th field by using `sub()` to replace the first newline character with nothing (i.e. it removes it).

Replacing the newline with `####` is also possible:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N put '$5 = sub($5,"\n","####")' file
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Z,KYEEI9,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1GH8####,KYEEID,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Y,KYEEIJ,1/1/2016 Contract Code
```

Note that the resulting field does not need quoting, which is why Miller does not add quotes by default.  If you want to retain the original quotes, use `--quote-original`:

```bash
$ mlr --csv -N --quote-original put '$5 = sub($5,"\n","####")' file
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Z,KYEEI9,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,"1GH8####",KYEEID,1/1/2016 Contract Code
KY,On,Ind ,Yes,1J5Y,KYEEIJ,1/1/2016 Contract Code
```

Use `-I` to perform an "in-place" edit.